# Pytorch and Ray is used to tune hyperparameter but the code runs error

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, hyperparameters, ray

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnywt.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOHVD.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHDC6.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DHRy.jpg)

Those are error messages I received.

I want to write the python code about tuning hyperparameters of convolution neural network.

I wrote a code based on this page (https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/examples/includes/pbt_convnet_function_example.html)

But, I think there are errors that I wrote.
I want to fit them, but I don't know where I have to fix.
Please help me...

I want to tune a lots of hyperparameters such as config.

How can I fix this and Is there any more simple way to write this?

```py
import argparse
import os
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

from ray import air, tune
from ray.air import session
from ray.air.checkpoint import Checkpoint
from ray.tune.schedulers import PopulationBasedTraining
```

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, conv1_filter, conv1_kernel, conv2_filter, conv2_kernel, dense1_units):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(10, conv1_filter, kernel_size=conv1_kernel)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(conv1_filter, conv2_filter, kernel_size=conv2_kernel)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        self.act = nn.Tanh()
        self.lin = nn.Linear(conv2_filter * 7 * 7 , dense1_units)
        self.result = nn.Linear(dense1_units, 10)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.pool(self.act(self.conv1(x)))
        out = self.pool(self.act(self.conv2(out)))
        out = self.act(self.lin(out.view(-1, conv2_filter * 7 * 7)))
        out = self.result(out)
        return out
```

```py
def training(config):
    step = 0
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(MNIST('data', train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor()), batch_size=config["batch_size"], shuffle=True)
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(MNIST('data', train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor()), batch_size=config["batch_size"], shuffle=True)
    model = Net(config["conv1_filter"], config["conv1_kernel"], config["conv2_filter"], config["conv2_kernel"], config["dense1_units"])
    optimizer = optim.SGD(
        model.parameters(),
        lr = config.get("learning_rate"),
    )
    
    if session.get_checkpoint():
        print("Loading from checkpoint.")
        loaded_checkpoint = session.get_checkpoint()
        with loaded_checkpoint.as_directory() as loaded_checkpoint_dir:
            path = os.path.join(loaded_checkpoint_dir, "checkpoint.pt")
            checkpoint = torch.load(path)
            model.load_state_dict(checkpoint["model"])
            step = checkpoint["step"]
    
    while True:
        train(model, optimizer, train_loader)
        acc = test(model, test_loader)
        checkpoint = None
        if step % 5 == 0:
            os.makedirs("my_model", exist_ok = True)
            torch.save(
                {
                    "step" : step,
                    "model" : model.state_dict()
                },
                "my_model/checkpoint.pt"
            )
            checkpoint = Checkpoint.from_directory("my_model")
        
        step += 1
        session.report({"mean_accuracy" : acc}, checkpoint = checkpoint)
```

```py
def test_best_model(results: tune.ResultGrid):
    with results.get_best_result().checkpoint.as_directory() as best_checkpoint_path:
        best_model = Net()
        best_checkpoint = torch.load(
            os.path.join(best_checkpoint_path, "checkpoint.pt")
        )
        best_model.load_state_dict(best_checkpoint["model"])
        test_acc = test(best_model, get_data_loaders()[1])
        print("best model accuracy: ", test_acc)
```

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    config = {
        "batch_size" : tune.choice([2, 4, 8, 16]),
        "conv1_filter" : tune.randint(1, 10),
        "conv1_kernel" : tune.randint(3, 5),
        "conv2_filter" : tune.randint(1, 10),
        "conv2_kernel" : tune.randint(3, 5),
        "dense1_units" : tune.qlograndint(5, 8, 2),
        "learning_rate" : tune.loguniform(1e-5, 1e-1)
    }
    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--smoke-test", action="store_true", help="Finish quickly for testing"
    )
    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    # __pbt_begin__
    scheduler = PopulationBasedTraining(
        time_attr="training_iteration",
        perturbation_interval=5,
        hyperparam_mutations = config
    )

    # __pbt_end__
    
    # __tune_begin__
    class CustomStopper(tune.Stopper):
        def __init__(self):
            self.should_stop = False

        def __call__(self, trial_id, result):
            max_iter = 5 if args.smoke_test else 100
            if not self.should_stop and result["mean_accuracy"] > 0.96:
                self.should_stop = True
            return self.should_stop or result["training_iteration"] >= max_iter

        def stop_all(self):
            return self.should_stop

    stopper = CustomStopper()

    tuner = tune.Tuner(
        training,
        run_config=air.RunConfig(
            name="pbt_test",
            stop=stopper,
            verbose=1,
            checkpoint_config=air.CheckpointConfig(
                checkpoint_score_attribute="mean_accuracy",
                num_to_keep=4,
            ),
        ),
        tune_config=tune.TuneConfig(
            scheduler=scheduler,
            metric="mean_accuracy",
            mode="max",
            num_samples=4,
        ),
        param_space=config
    )
    results = tuner.fit()
    # __tune_end__

    test_best_model(results)
```

Comment: Hi! Can you share the errors you are receiving?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your concern. Because the error messages are too long, I attach them as image file on script.

Comment: `from torchvision.datasets import MNIST` should be `from torchvision import datasets`

Comment: Thank you, I edit that part but the code makes error yet... I attach another error in this page.

Comment: I think the problem is the part "train is not defined", but the code of reference page (https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/examples/includes/pbt_convnet_function_example.html) works fine. I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you need more interactive help. Consider joining the Ray slack, link here https://www.ray.io/community